# reportview using sqldataadapter

Tags: vb.net, vba

is there a way to make a reportviewer using sqldataadapter? is it possible?
It seems that I can't find a way to get it on datasource.

```
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source = pc11-pc\kim; Initial Catalog = mypos; User ID = sa; Password = 123")
    Dim sqlstr As String = "Select * from Supplier"
    Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    adp.Fill(dt)

    'reportviewer1.datasources = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the glimps of it...

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
 Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)

 Try
  conn.Open()
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
  Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
  adapter.Fill(dt)
 Catch ex As Exception
   MessageBox.Show("Error")
 Finally
 conn.Close()
 End Try

 Dim ds As New ReportDataSource(dataSourceName, dt)
 rViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
 rViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds)
 rViewer.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

Comment: what you mean by this line sir?                                                      Dim ds As New ReportDataSource(dataSourceName, dt)

Comment: (dt.TableName, dt) that's what you need.

Comment: I do have error on "ReportDataSource". do I need to create a .rdlc file?

Comment: rViewer is your viewer name

Comment: No you don't, just make sure your getting data back

Comment: yeah my rviewer is reportviewer1... but I do have an error on "ReportDataSource"

Comment: Make sure you have a datatable name.after dim dt put this below it : dt.TableName = "test"

Comment: here's my error  'type "ReportDataSource" is not defined'

Comment: If your still getting the error try putting "test" in place of dt.TableName

Comment: yes sir, still having error on "ReportDataSource" is not defined.

Comment: Dim ds As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt)

Comment: it's okay now sir. But when I run the program there's a message: "The Source of the report definition has not been specified"

Comment: Report definition is the RDL (or RDLC) file. You can specify it by setting rViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath property to the path of the RDL file.

Comment: so, I will need to design a new report using wizard? am I right sir?

Comment: Yes if you don't have one, my understanding you had one. Once you do this just set the report path to point to it. After that you should be golden. Also if this has helped don't forget to accept.

Comment: I have another problem. "A Data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'dataset1'"

Comment: The problem your having is getting your data it seems, if that is the case set break points and see where it fails?

Comment: I already post my code there.. when I design a new report I'll be required to make a dataset. does it conflict with my sqlcommand there?

Answer (score 0):

here's my code sir

```
       'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'myposDataSet5.Product' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.ProductTableAdapter.Fill(Me.myposDataSet5.Product)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source = pc11-pc\kim; Initial Catalog = mypos; User ID = sa; Password = 123")

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Product", conn)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

    'Dim ReportDataSource As DataTable = New DataTable
    'Dim ds As New ReportDataSource(dt.TableName = "test", dt)
    Dim ds As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "D:\visual studio\mypos\mypos\Report3.rdlc"
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```